# Copyrights, using similar concepts of design etc

Tags: html, css, design-patterns

My question is rather simple, but affect serious issue.

When I'm developing websites / widgets and other web applications may I use similar approach in design cases like other pages have? It's just my inspiration.

For example. I'm not copying piece of codes, graphics, but using some very useful strategies and concepts, but

- find very comfortable Google new navigation (top, dark bar)
- icon navigation and positioning like in Google+ or Google Maps is nice in my opinion
- apple.com boxes with rounded corners and delicate shadow is just perfect
- etc. etc.

So... what if I create administration panel for example finding inspirations in that pages? Similiar but in different dimmensions and colors , using different buttons layout, using my own code and graphics (or with royalty-free licence on icons, btw. similiar to iPhone icons ;) )

What about copyrights and intellectual property?

Comment: For this question you ***need*** to ***consult a lawyer*** in your own country (for the relevant legal framework and understanding). This is [off-topic for Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/).

Comment: It _could_ be considered a "derivative" work if it's too similar to the original.  But these things are a matter of opinion and it ultimately depends on what a judge or jury decides, if it ever got that far.  Of course this is a legal question where only a lawyer should advise you based on your particular circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting ideas**

Collecting ideas from other sites is normal and probably the right thing you can do! Like checking out features and way of others do things. That's called research -- taking bad and good from other sites and making yours better.

**Using similar elements**

Its pretty impossible to get sued, because you used similar toolbar on your site, as google has. Of course being a copycat is not a nice thing to do. Unless you are getting only the idea and of course create the full toolbar from ground up.

**As example:** I really liked the orange toolbar in new google analytics. So I used it in a UI for a big system. I only used the tab and icon look. Also made it in blue not orange.. That's taking some good idea and making it fit for your current project.

**What you shouldn't do**

You must remember, that all logos and images are copyrighted (unless stated otherwise; also, some sites copyright their own logos and layout graphics, but offer the content as free to use.)

**Making a parody-site**

Technically you can go as far as copying a full site. However, this is on the very critical verge, where you could get sued. However:

- If you don't use any of the logos or trademarked elements
- You make all graphics and photos yourself (dress all your models the same)
- Create all code from ground up (copyrighting html and css might be possible, but if you change it a little, or better yet make it your own.. its not the same)
- Maybe even put the sidebar or menus on the opposite side or something

If you follow these points, you should be safe from getting sued, however copying somebody's site is not a nice thing to do. Unless, you want to play a prank on your friend or creating a fansite of a site of some kind.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a lawyer, but I also have never been sued! These are general facts, on how you get things done on the web. 85% of worlds ideas are already being done, but who said you cant make the same ideas better?!

Comment: Yeah, that is the answer that I expected. Of course, code is created from basis, all is done by me. I'm just find useful tools and solutions and put it together with my vision of this. All in all, all cars are similar, so why website cannot be? And... I'm sure this site I'm working on will not be common, only for some people... Thanks :)

Comment: This is a terrible answer!  A derivative work is a derivative work... following the dubious "legal" advice of @Kalle, you could duplicate the Apple® logo or the Coke® website as long as you created them from scratch... this cannot be more wrong! (at least in the US).  You cannot duplicate the "look & feel" of somebody else's work without risking copyright infringement **even if you did it from scratch**.

Comment: Well, I thought I will add, that logos and trademarks are obviously copyrighted. However, he didn't ask about logos, but layout. You can duplicate sites, by changing the keyelements a little and of course not use the trademarked elements.

Comment: That's true. Logos and trademarks are fully copyrighted. Hmm... It's a trivial example, but stackoverflow has the same top bar like google right now (only in different color) I was wondering about something like that. And like @Sparky672 said, Apple and Coke are ® , not their websites at all.

Comment: You both should read up on this topic (derivative work) or consult an attorney before declaring _"it's legal as long as you created it from ground up"_.  Firstly, if you create an original logo, book, painting, script, website, song, etc. **your** copyright on _your_ work is automatic.  Secondly, the Apple® logo is just an example... **it does not matter if it's a website or logo**... if you used enough elements (same look & feel) from the original, it **might** be considered a "derivative work" which _could_ be a copyright violation.  It does **not** matter if you created it from scratch!

Comment: Well actually, (lets use bunnyears) you should "relax". Because, we are talking about pages layouts (look) and menus, functions etc (feel.) I can make a site looking just like your homepage on the layout aspect. I can even "parody" your pictures or even your logo. You can sue me, but based on my countries "laws" (where the site will be hosted,) I will win the case. "Sparky" if you would just take a "deep breath" and understand that we are talking about "inspiration" and page layouts.. little elements.. Like googles toolbar for example..

Comment: @Kalle:  Please keep your personal remarks to yourself... they are too chatty and way off-topic.  You posted a really poor answer full of dubious advice and I'm calling you out on it.

Comment: @Kalle:  Despite being tempted, I made no personal comments here.  I simply voted it down and commented on it.  Unless you're an international lawyer, you really have no basis to claim how copyright law works in "most countries".  I know how it works in the US but I will not advise anyone about how _"everything is legal"_ or _"everything is cool"_ since I'm not a lawyer.  Posting a [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) in your answer helps too.

Comment: In general, really good answers would contain words/phrases like, _"maybe"_, _"might"_, _"could"_, _"it depends"_, _"I'm not a lawyer"_ or _"I'm a lawyer"_, and _"you should consult legal counsel"_.  Really bad answers contain phrases like, _"always"_, _"everything"_, _"that's totally legal"_, and _"just do this or that and you're cool"_.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited my answer to make things more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I AM NOT A LAWYER AND THIS IS ***NOT*** LEGAL ADVICE!

You cannot copyright things that are considered useful or practical, Like rounded corners and shadows. Yet in Intellectual property there are "Trade Dress" which means: The total image and overall appearance of a product or service; protected under common law principles to trademark law.

But as mentioned above this can be a very fine line and ultimately it is up to the judge/jury to decide did you infringe.

If you cannot afford a lawyer I would recommend doing alot of reading and studying. A book that hes helped me out a alot is: [Intellectual Property: Patents, Trademarks, and Copyrights by Richard Stim. Published by West Legal Studies.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1413309208)  That book gives you a good base and is used in Law Schools and you can understand it.